# return a list of running applications (not processes) in the command line, OSX

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I have a computer that I want to run in a kiosk-ish mode. The behavior that I want is to close applications that others might open. Here is the pseudocode

```
#!/bin/sh
# Get list of Open applications
# Close anything not on a specified application white list
```

Here's the hitch, I don't fully understand, nor do I want to wade through all the garbage that comes back when you run a query for processes such as "ps -aux"

I really just want to get a list of the open applications that one would see when using cmd+tab and then process *that* list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to not let the users open those applications in the first place?
In that case have a look at "parental control". Here's a link for [Mavericks](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14414).

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll look into it. Thx.